# Best way to hide a global header in a Angular App

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing

So I'd like to implement a global header in a app, the app-header would be on top of the `<router-outlet>`, in some pages I'd like to modify the appearance of the header or flat out hide it. I've seen implementations of this in the past, where you have a HeaderService and the Header then subscribes to one or more values of this service, so other components can call the service and maybe set flags to hide the header and what not.

What I dislike of this approach is that then every single page would have to specify if if it wants or not the header(using the hiding scenario as a example), what I'd like is a default case for all pages, (show the header) and then allow other pages to opt out of showing the header without this affecting the other pages. Would anyone know of a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an additional routing level:

```
[
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutWithHeaderComponent
    children: [ <the routes with a header here ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutWithoutHeaderComponent
    children: [ <the routes without a header here ]
  }
]
```

Both layout components would of course have a `<router-outlet>` in their template where the child route component would be inserted.

Comment: Ah, this seems like it would work pretty well for just hiding the header, but I would also like to modify the header depending on the component, perhaps add more options to it, or remove. I pretty much would like to have header variants and be able to control from each page which is used, but if none is specified use a default one.

Comment: Then make the routes with a custom header children of the second route above, and insert the header in the template of the component itself, passing inputs to customize it. And make the routes using the standard header children of the first route above.